# What's the difference between lib/ and plugins/ in symfony?

Tags: naming-conventions, symfony1

Library and Plugins seem similar,what's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

`/plugins` is where Symfony Plugins are kept (installed / developed yourself), `/lib` is where more project specific files are kept such as your model / forms etc.